# select sum of max values from multiple incrementing sequences

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate a sum of the max values from sequence of increment values.

for this data set:

```
time_stamp count
1467820429  6 *
1467820428  5
1467820427  4
1467820426  3
1467820416  2
1467820415  1
1467820413  0
1467820412  3 *
1467820411  2
1467820409  1
1467820408  0
1467820405  1 *
1467820404  0
1467820400  5 *
```

answer = 6 + 3 + 1 + 5 = 15

how can i write a MySQL compatible SQL statement to acheve this

Comment: can you explain the logic how you identified them as max values

Comment: It is going to pain doing it in `Mysql`, When the other major `RDBMS` having some good functions to do such things in easier way

Comment: next value is lower than it

Comment: how can the same time_stamp have 2 different counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(a.cnt)
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.time_stamp) next
         FROM my_table x
         LEFT
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.time_stamp > x.time_stamp
        GROUP 
           BY x.time_stamp
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table b
    ON b.time_stamp = a.next
   AND b.cnt > a.cnt
 WHERE b.cnt IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get it in following method

```
mysql> select time_stamp,count,if (count=0,@curRank :=0,@curRank := @curRank + 1) as rank from ff,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r;
+------------+-------+------+
| time_stamp | count | rank |
+------------+-------+------+
| 1467820429 |     6 |    1 |
| 1467820428 |     5 |    2 |
| 1467820427 |     4 |    3 |
| 1467820426 |     3 |    4 |
| 1467820415 |     2 |    5 |
| 1467820415 |     1 |    6 |
| 1467820413 |     0 |    0 |
| 1467820412 |     3 |    1 |
| 1467820411 |     2 |    2 |
| 1467820409 |     1 |    3 |
| 1467820408 |     0 |    0 |
| 1467820405 |     1 |    1 |
| 1467820404 |     0 |    0 |
| 1467820408 |     5 |    1 |
+------------+-------+------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM (select time_stamp,count,if (count=0,@curRank :=0,@curRank := @curRank + 1) as rank from ff,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r) t WHERE rank=1;
+------------+-------+------+
| time_stamp | count | rank |
+------------+-------+------+
| 1467820408 |     5 |    1 |
| 1467820412 |     3 |    1 |
| 1467820429 |     6 |    1 |
| 1467820405 |     1 |    1 |
+------------+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> SELECT sum(count) as total FROM 
(select time_stamp,count,if (count=0,@curRank :=0,@curRank := @curRank + 1) as rank from ff,
(SELECT @curRank := 0) r) t WHERE rank=1;
    +-------+
    | total |
    +-------+
    |    15 |
    +-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

you can get it with simple inner query

Comment: Without an ORDER BY clause, this cannot reliably work. I note that your data set (presently) differs from the OP's.

Comment: @Strawberry yes agreed . simple we can order by it using timestamp. no harm on that

Comment: Also, the test isn't `when count = 0` (although that was my misunderstanding too, and it will work in this instance). As per the comments, the test is when `next is less than previous`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments there is no efficient way to do this in `Mysql` atleast to my knowledge

Try this

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
             WHEN `count` >= prev_cnt THEN `count` 
             ELSE 0 
           END) 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               IFnull((SELECT `count` 
                       FROM   yourtable b 
                       WHERE  a.`time_stamp` < b.`time_stamp` 
                       ORDER  BY `time_stamp` LIMIT 1), `count`) AS prev_cnt 
        FROM   yourtable a) c
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify when a value shifts.  One way to get the previous value uses variables:

```
select sum(count)
from (select t.*,
             (if((@old_c := @c) is null, 0, -- never happens
                 if((@c := count) is not null, @old_c, @old_c)
                )
             ) as prev_count
      from t cross join
           (select @c := -1) params
      order by time_stamp
     ) t
where prev_count >= count;
```

The expression for getting the previous count is a bit complicated.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions, so the assignment of the new value of count and returning the old value needs to be in a single expression.

Comment: Is there a missing comma? And an overabundance of 't's? Even correcting for those, and missing parentheses, I don't think this is quite right.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I do think it is correct (I fixed a missing closing paren) and should have the best performance.

Comment: `t.*
             (if( ` cannot be correct. I agree that if it can be done (I couldn't figure out how) then using variables could be faster, but there are still errors here.

Answer (score -1):

You need GROUP BY and HAVING, like this:

```
select sum ( count ) 
from table
group by time_stamp
having count = max(count)
```

Comment: **NMDV**, This will not pull the expected result

Answer (score -2):

Very simple solution : 
    1- take the lag of the column time_stamp

```
2- take the difference of orif time_stamp column and the lag column 

3- sum the values of count after filtering out the records for -1 

    +------------+-------+------+-----------------+-------+
| a          | b     | c    | d               | a-d   |
| time_stamp | count | flag | lag_time_stamp  | diff  |
| 1467820429 | 6     | *    | nulll           | null  |
| 1467820428 | 5     |      | 1467820429      | -1    |
| 1467820427 | 4     |      | 1467820428      | -1    |
| 1467820426 | 3     |      | 1467820427      | -1    |
| 1467820416 | 2     | *    | 1467820426      | -10   |
| 1467820415 | 1     |      | 1467820416      | -1    |
| 1467820413 | 3     | *    | 1467820415      | -2    |
| 1467820412 | 3     |      | 1467820413      | -1    |
| 1467820411 | 2     |      | 1467820412      | -1    |
| 1467820409 | 1     | *    | 1467820411      | -2    |
| 1467820408 | 0     |      | 1467820409      | -1    |
| 1467820405 | 1     | *    | 1467820408      | -3    |
| 1467820404 | 0     |      | 1467820405      | -1    |
| 1467820400 | 5     | *    | 1467820404      | -4    |
+------------+-------+------+-----------------+-------+

--sum the values of the table that we got after filtering the records for -1

+------------+-------+
| time_stamp | count |
+------------+-------+
| 1467820429 |     6 |
| 1467820416 |     2 |
| 1467820413 |     3 |
| 1467820409 |     1 |
| 1467820405 |     1 |
| 1467820400 |     5 |
+------------+-------+
```